# I am having trouble with my Parse login and sign up

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to incorporate twitter login into my app, but overtime I click on the twitter button on the simulator I get this error message:

```
2015-10-10 20:06:27.432 Parse Twitter Login[7886:1261672] ***
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack: (   0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010310cc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib   
0x0000000104c7abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45    2   CoreFoundation      
0x000000010301684f -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 383   3   CoreFoundation             
0x000000010302959b +[NSDictionary
dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59  4   Parse Twitter Login   
0x0000000101b3d322 -[PF_Twitter
_showWebViewDialogAsync:requestSecret:] + 206   5   Parse Twitter Login                 0x0000000101b3ef76 __38-[PF_Twitter
_performWebViewAuthAsync]_block_invoke_2 + 232  6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108d6f186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12    7  
libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108d8e614
_dispatch_client_callout + 8    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108d76a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664     9  
CoreFoundation                      0x00000001030741f9
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9  10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103035dcb __CFRunLoopRun
+ 2043  11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103035366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470   12  GraphicsServices                   
0x0000000105310a3e GSEventRunModal + 161    13  UIKit                   
0x00000001039ad900 UIApplicationMain + 1282     14  Parse Twitter Login  
0x0000000101a9a2e7 main + 135   15  libdyld.dylib                      
0x0000000108dc3145 start + 1    16  ???                                
0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

could anyone help me out?

Comment: Give details of your setup and initialisation of parse and twitter details

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance forgot to init the Parse SDK?

```
// Init parse
    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "appID"
        $0.clientKey = "clientKey"
        $0.server = "https://yourparseserver.com"
    }
    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```